# I want to deploy next.js with nginx - without node.js server. How Can I deploy without node.js server?

Tags: nginx, next.js

Here is my code.

I think I am running the node server now and then connecting it to the nginx server.

I want to deploy next.js with Nginx but without node.js server
How Can I..?

```json
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;


}

server{
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }


}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to deploy your Next.js app as static HTML? If so check out [Static HTML Export](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export).

Comment: I don't know how to set the path to the static file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.